# awk command to delete rows if it has number as the first character of first column in a tsv file

Tags: csv, awk

I am trying to delete rows if it has number as the first character in the first column in a tsv file.

```
abc london
def paris
4ge berlin
323 rome
xyz prague
#56 Bern
```

I would like to delete (rows: 4ge, 323,#56). What I tried is something like this

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{$1=/^[0-9]/; print $1,$2}' train.tsv > train.tsv
```

Comment: You can't do `train.tsv > train.tsv` - it will overwrite the input and screw it up.  Instead, write to a second file, or do `train.tsv | sponge train.tsv` (you may need to install `sponge` from the package `moreutils`).

Comment: @JohnZwinck +1 for recommending `sponge`!

Comment: `sed` alternative `sed  '/^[0-9]/d'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '!/^[[:digit:]]/' file
```

Since it is the first column you can simply check if the whole line starts (not) with a number. If you would be interested in any other column you can use (for example second column):

```
awk '$2 !~ /^[[:digit:]]/' file
```

---

Btw, you may miss the print command here. That's because it is default command, meaning

```
awk '!/^[[:digit:]]/' file
```

is the same as

```
awk '!/^[[:digit:]]/{print}' file
```

which is the same as

```
awk '!/^[[:digit:]]/{print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the kind of job grep was invented to do:

```
grep -v '^[0-9]'
```

The difference between that and `grep '^[^0-9]'` is that the former will print blank lines while the latter won't.